# iOS Swift Parsing JSON Response From Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

This is the actual JSON response that I received from my server:

```
{
  "case_details": {
    "status": "PENDING",
    "caseNumber": "ARBIT.CASE(C)/1/2017",
    "party": "COMBITHERM APPARATE-UND ANLAGENBAU GMBH .Vs. COXWELL DOMES ENGINEERS PVT. LTD. & ANR",
    "pAdv": "MR. DEVENDRA SINGH",
    "updatedOn": "24-04-2017",
    }
}
```

But when I getting this same JSON response in swift, It receives like

```
    {
  "case_details"= {
    "status"= "PENDING",
    "caseNumber"= "ARBIT.CASE(C)/1/2017",
    "party"= "COMBITHERM APPARATE-UND ANLAGENBAU GMBH .Vs. COXWELL DOMES ENGINEERS PVT. LTD. & ANR",
    "pAdv"= "MR. DEVENDRA SINGH",
    "updatedOn"= "24-04-2017",
    }
}
```

Problem is `:` changed as `=` How to I fix it?
My tried Code:

```
Alamofire.request(baseurl, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
let statuscode = response.response?.statusCode
switch response.result
{
case .success(_):
if ( statuscode == 200)
{
   let JSON = response.result.value!
   //JSON Returns `=` instead of `:`
}
case .failure(let error):
print("Request Failed With Error:\(error)")
}
```

Comment: Be careful that neither of your messages is a valid JSON message, look at the extra comma before the last `}`

Comment: its does not create any probelm

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik It won't Make any problem but in some response I need to send back this same JSON response to my server. In server side they are expecting it as `:` not `=`. Thats my problem

Comment: add some code for parsing.

Comment: The first example is **before**, the second is **after** the parsing. Most likely Alamofire parses the JSON under the hood and you get back a dictionary.

Comment: You are printing the JSON dictionary from backend right? I believe this might just be how the `description` property formats the dictionary... It is just how it is formatted when printing.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik above post updated with my tried code

Comment: @KKRocks can you share me code for parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
  Alamofire.request("your url", method: .get, parameters: parameter).validate().responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let result = response.result.value {
                let JSON = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                callback(JSON as AnyObject, true)                        
                  }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
```